# wallet_addEthereumChain is not working in metamask android app

Tags: blockchain, metamask, dapps, javascript, ethereum-wallet-dapp

I am using `wallet_addEthereumChain` RPC function to add the custom network in metamask android app through our Dapp but it is showing an error `wrong chainid`. The chainid(80001) is correct and the code is working fine in a desktop browser using metamask extension but the same code gives an error in metamask android app. Below is code that I am using:

```
try {
  const res = await window.ethereum.request({
    method: "wallet_switchEthereumChain",
    params: [{ chainId: "0x13881" }],
  });
} catch (switchError) {
  if (switchError.code === 4902) {
    try {
      await window.ethereum.request({
        id: 1,
        jsonrpc: "2.0",
        method: "wallet_addEthereumChain",
        params: [
          {
            chainId: "0x13881",
            rpcUrls: ["https://rpc-mumbai.maticvigil.com"],
            chainName: "Polygon Testnet Mumbai",
            nativeCurrency: {
              name: "tMATIC",
              symbol: "tMATIC", // 2-6 characters long
              decimals: 18,
            },
            blockExplorerUrls: ["https://mumbai.polygonscan.com/"],
          },
        ],
      });
    } catch (addError) {
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const switchMetamaskWalletChain = async () => {
  try {
    await ethereum.request({
      method: "wallet_switchEthereumChain",
      params: [{ chainId: activeChain.hex }]
    });
  } catch (switchError) {
    if (isMobile) {
      const errorCode = switchError.data?.originalError?.code
      if (errorCode && errorCode === 4902) {
        await addChain()
      }
    } else {
      if (switchError.code === 4902) {
      
        await addChain()
      }
    }
    
    // handle other "switch" errors
    console.error(switchError);
  }
};
```

If you are using mobile metamask, wallet_switchEthereumChain request error is going to be thrown in different error format.
In mobile, error code is `switchError.data?.originalError?.code`.

Hope it works!